# SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal while finding last occurance

Tags: python

I'm trying to extract file name from a long string. So I used following code to extract the index of last "\" so that I can use substring

```
z='C:\\MLE\\input\\images\\044c0912-68d1-11e8-8db8-0242ac110002.jpg'
a=z.rindex('\')
```

But It's giving error message `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`

Can you suggest me what wrong I'm doing?

I'm using python 3.6

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but consider using [`os.path.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.split) when extracting information from path names. That way, it will work regardless of what separator character your OS uses.

Comment: `a=z.rindex('\\')`

Comment: Write this a=z.rindex('\\') . When you use single "\" then it's assumed that you will put another character after this, because "\" is an escape character.

Comment: @thesilkworm: `r'\'` won't work; you need `'\\'`.

Comment: Did anyone mention yet that the \ needs to be escaped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a=z.rindex('\')

the backslash escapes the single quote, so the interpreter reaches the end of the line without terminating the string. ("EOL while scanning string literal")

Comment: Comments can solve this problem. So please try to avoid answering this type of questions. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest using `pathlib`.

```
from pathlib import Path
p = Path('C:') / 'MLE' / 'input' / ... / '1234.jpg'
filename = p.name
print(filename)  # '1234.jpg'
```